# Java Running Selenium Grid as a standard Java Software

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I'm building a small Java project to test my website using Selenium. I can create node, hub, run a test using TestNg on eclipse.

But I want to make it more automatic like I can feed my URL, ports, the number of instances in a variable, and then, the test runs according to that. I have 2 classes right now and want to combine them: calling the Selenium test class to execute from another class.
Here's my current code:

```
//Selenim Test Code
package com.basusingh.scbot;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.UnexpectedAlertBehaviour;

import java.util.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class StreamMain {
    
    WebDriver driver;
    String baseURL, nodeURL;
    private Map<String, Object> vars;
    JavascriptExecutor js;
    
    
    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/chromedriver.exe");
        nodeURL = "http://192.168.100.3:4444/wd/hub";
        System.out.println("Chrome Browser Initiated");
        
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();            
        capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
        capabilities.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WINDOWS);
        
        ChromeOptions cap = new ChromeOptions(); 
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR,
                          UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
        cap.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", "enable-automation");
        
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL), cap);
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void afterTest() {
        driver.quit();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void sampleTest() { 
        driver.get("https://google.com"); 
        driver.close();

    }

}
```

My main class to create hub, node and execute the test:

```
package com.basusingh.scbot;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class CMDTest {
    
    static String hubPort = "4497";
    static String fileLocation = "C:\\file.jar";
    static int nodeCount = 5;
    

    static String chromeDriverLocation = "C:\\chromedriver.exe";
    static String hubRegisterUrlForNode = "http://192.168.100.5:" + hubPort + "/wd/hub";
    static String chromeMaxInstance = "20";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        System.out.println("Starting Hub");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar " + fileLocation + " -role hub -port " + hubPort);
        
        for(int i = 1; i<=nodeCount; i++) {
            System.out.println("Starting Node: " + String.valueOf(i));
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=" + chromeDriverLocation + " -jar " + fileLocation + " -role node -hub " + hubRegisterUrlForNode + " -browser browserName=\"chrome\",version=ANY,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=" + chromeMaxInstance);
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void printResults(Process process) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I call and run the StreamMain test class inside my CMDTest class. I can guess a practice like I call the setUp() and sampleTest() from StreamMain inside my CMDTest class but not sure if it will work. what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Quite unusual approach. That said, take a look at how to launch JUnit test class programatically:

[Running JUnit Tests Programmatically, from a Java Application](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-tests-run-programmatically-from-java)

```
JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
junit.addListener(new TextListener(System.out));
junit.run(StreamMain.class);
```

This should honor all the junit specific configuration in `SteamMain.class`

More common approach would be to have a CI server, like Jenkins take care of setting up environment and grid and all that, then run tests as a pipeline step. There is a lot of reinventing a wheel in your example.